# Python: Expand a dataframe row-wise based on datetime

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ID       Date  Value
783  C 2018-02-23  0.704
580  B 2018-08-04 -1.189
221  A 2018-08-10 -0.788
228  A 2018-08-17  0.038
578  B 2018-08-02  1.188
```

What I want is expanding the dataframe based on `Date` column to 1-month earlier, and fill `ID` with the same person, and fill `Value` with `nan` until the last observation.

The expected result is similar to this:

```
    ID        Date  Value
0    C  2018/01/24    nan
1    C  2018/01/25    nan
2    C  2018/01/26    nan
3    C  2018/01/27    nan
4    C  2018/01/28    nan
5    C  2018/01/29    nan
6    C  2018/01/30    nan
7    C  2018/01/31    nan
8    C  2018/02/01    nan
9    C  2018/02/02    nan
10   C  2018/02/03    nan
11   C  2018/02/04    nan
12   C  2018/02/05    nan
13   C  2018/02/06    nan
14   C  2018/02/07    nan
15   C  2018/02/08    nan
16   C  2018/02/09    nan
17   C  2018/02/10    nan
18   C  2018/02/11    nan
19   C  2018/02/12    nan
20   C  2018/02/13    nan
21   C  2018/02/14    nan
22   C  2018/02/15    nan
23   C  2018/02/16    nan
24   C  2018/02/17    nan
25   C  2018/02/18    nan
26   C  2018/02/19    nan
27   C  2018/02/20    nan
28   C  2018/02/21    nan
29   C  2018/02/22    nan
30   C  2018/02/23  1.093
31   B  2018/07/05    nan
32   B  2018/07/06    nan
33   B  2018/07/07    nan
34   B  2018/07/08    nan
35   B  2018/07/09    nan
36   B  2018/07/10    nan
37   B  2018/07/11    nan
38   B  2018/07/12    nan
39   B  2018/07/13    nan
40   B  2018/07/14    nan
41   B  2018/07/15    nan
42   B  2018/07/16    nan
43   B  2018/07/17    nan
44   B  2018/07/18    nan
45   B  2018/07/19    nan
46   B  2018/07/20    nan
47   B  2018/07/21    nan
48   B  2018/07/22    nan
49   B  2018/07/23    nan
50   B  2018/07/24    nan
51   B  2018/07/25    nan
52   B  2018/07/26    nan
53   B  2018/07/27    nan
54   B  2018/07/28    nan
55   B  2018/07/29    nan
56   B  2018/07/30    nan
57   B  2018/07/31    nan
58   B  2018/08/01    nan
59   B  2018/08/02    nan
60   B  2018/08/03    nan
61   B  2018/08/04  0.764
62   A  2018/07/11    nan
63   A  2018/07/12    nan
64   A  2018/07/13    nan
65   A  2018/07/14    nan
66   A  2018/07/15    nan
67   A  2018/07/16    nan
68   A  2018/07/17    nan
69   A  2018/07/18    nan
70   A  2018/07/19    nan
71   A  2018/07/20    nan
72   A  2018/07/21    nan
73   A  2018/07/22    nan
74   A  2018/07/23    nan
75   A  2018/07/24    nan
76   A  2018/07/25    nan
77   A  2018/07/26    nan
78   A  2018/07/27    nan
79   A  2018/07/28    nan
80   A  2018/07/29    nan
81   A  2018/07/30    nan
82   A  2018/07/31    nan
83   A  2018/08/01    nan
84   A  2018/08/02    nan
85   A  2018/08/03    nan
86   A  2018/08/04    nan
87   A  2018/08/05    nan
88   A  2018/08/06    nan
89   A  2018/08/07    nan
90   A  2018/08/08    nan
91   A  2018/08/09    nan
92   A  2018/08/10  2.144
93   A  2018/07/18    nan
94   A  2018/07/19    nan
95   A  2018/07/20    nan
96   A  2018/07/21    nan
97   A  2018/07/22    nan
98   A  2018/07/23    nan
99   A  2018/07/24    nan
100  A  2018/07/25    nan
101  A  2018/07/26    nan
102  A  2018/07/27    nan
103  A  2018/07/28    nan
104  A  2018/07/29    nan
105  A  2018/07/30    nan
106  A  2018/07/31    nan
107  A  2018/08/01    nan
108  A  2018/08/02    nan
109  A  2018/08/03    nan
110  A  2018/08/04    nan
111  A  2018/08/05    nan
112  A  2018/08/06    nan
113  A  2018/08/07    nan
114  A  2018/08/08    nan
115  A  2018/08/09    nan
116  A  2018/08/10    nan
117  A  2018/08/11    nan
118  A  2018/08/12    nan
119  A  2018/08/13    nan
120  A  2018/08/14    nan
121  A  2018/08/15    nan
122  A  2018/08/16    nan
123  A  2018/08/17  0.644
124  B  2018/07/03    nan
125  B  2018/07/04    nan
126  B  2018/07/05    nan
127  B  2018/07/06    nan
128  B  2018/07/07    nan
129  B  2018/07/08    nan
130  B  2018/07/09    nan
131  B  2018/07/10    nan
132  B  2018/07/11    nan
133  B  2018/07/12    nan
134  B  2018/07/13    nan
135  B  2018/07/14    nan
136  B  2018/07/15    nan
137  B  2018/07/16    nan
138  B  2018/07/17    nan
139  B  2018/07/18    nan
140  B  2018/07/19    nan
141  B  2018/07/20    nan
142  B  2018/07/21    nan
143  B  2018/07/22    nan
144  B  2018/07/23    nan
145  B  2018/07/24    nan
146  B  2018/07/25    nan
147  B  2018/07/26    nan
148  B  2018/07/27    nan
149  B  2018/07/28    nan
150  B  2018/07/29    nan
151  B  2018/07/30    nan
152  B  2018/07/31    nan
153  B  2018/08/01    nan
154  B  2018/08/02 -0.767
```

The source data can be created as below:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
import numpy as np


df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID' : list(chain.from_iterable([['A'] * 365, ['B'] * 365, ['C'] * 365])),
        'Date' : pd.date_range(start = '2018-01-01', end = '2018-12-31').tolist() + pd.date_range(start = '2018-01-01', end = '2018-12-31').tolist() + pd.date_range(start = '2018-01-01', end = '2018-12-31').tolist(),
        'Value' : np.random.randn(365 * 3)
        })

df_1 = df_1.sample(5, random_state = 123)
```

Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another `DataFrame` with previous months, then join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), create `DatetimeIndex`, so possible use `groupby` with `resample` by `d` for days for add all values between:

```
df_2 = df_1.assign(Date = df_1['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=1) + pd.DateOffset(days=1),
                   Value = np.nan)

df = (pd.concat([df_2, df_1], sort=False)
        .reset_index()
        .set_index('Date')
        .groupby('index', sort=False)
        .resample('D')
        .ffill()
        .reset_index(level=1)
        .drop('index', 1)
        .rename_axis(None))
print (df)

          Date ID     Value
783 2018-01-24  C       NaN
783 2018-01-25  C       NaN
783 2018-01-26  C       NaN
783 2018-01-27  C       NaN
783 2018-01-28  C       NaN
..         ... ..       ...
578 2018-07-29  B       NaN
578 2018-07-30  B       NaN
578 2018-07-31  B       NaN
578 2018-08-01  B       NaN
578 2018-08-02  B  0.562684

[155 rows x 3 columns]
```

Another solution with list comprehension and `concat`, but last is necessary back filling of columns for index and `ID`, solution working if no missing value in original `ID` column:

```
offset = pd.DateOffset(months=1) + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
df=pd.concat([df_1.iloc[[i]].reset_index().set_index('Date').reindex(pd.date_range(d-offset,d))
                      for i, d in enumerate(df_1['Date'])], sort=False)
df = (df.assign(index = df['index'].bfill().astype(int), ID = df['ID'].bfill())
        .rename_axis('Date')
        .reset_index()
        .set_index('index')
        .rename_axis(None)
)
print (df)

          Date ID     Value
783 2018-01-24  C       NaN
783 2018-01-25  C       NaN
783 2018-01-26  C       NaN
783 2018-01-27  C       NaN
783 2018-01-28  C       NaN
..         ... ..       ...
578 2018-07-29  B       NaN
578 2018-07-30  B       NaN
578 2018-07-31  B       NaN
578 2018-08-01  B       NaN
578 2018-08-02  B  1.224345

[155 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a date range in the "Date" column, then explode it.
Then group the "Value" column by the index and set values to nan but the last.
Finally reset the index.

```
def drange(t):
    return pd.date_range( t-pd.DateOffset(months=1)+pd.DateOffset(days=1),t,freq="D",normalize=True)

df["Date"]= df["Date"].transform(drange)

      ID                                               Date  Value
index                                                             
783    C  DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-24', '2018-01-25', '20...  0.704
580    B  DatetimeIndex(['2018-07-05', '2018-07-06', '20... -1.189
221    A  DatetimeIndex(['2018-07-11', '2018-07-12', '20... -0.788
228    A  DatetimeIndex(['2018-07-18', '2018-07-19', '20...  0.038
578    B  DatetimeIndex(['2018-07-03', '2018-07-04', '20...  1.188


df= df.reset_index(drop=True).explode(column="Date")

   ID       Date  Value
0   C 2018-01-24  0.704
0   C 2018-01-25  0.704
0   C 2018-01-26  0.704
0   C 2018-01-27  0.704
0   C 2018-01-28  0.704
.. ..        ...    ...
4   B 2018-07-29  1.188
4   B 2018-07-30  1.188
4   B 2018-07-31  1.188
4   B 2018-08-01  1.188
4   B 2018-08-02  1.188


df["Value"]= df.groupby(level=0)["Value"].transform(lambda v: [np.nan]*(len(v)-1)+[v.iloc[0]])
df= df.reset_index(drop=True)

    ID       Date  Value
0    C 2018-01-24    NaN
1    C 2018-01-25    NaN
2    C 2018-01-26    NaN
3    C 2018-01-27    NaN
4    C 2018-01-28    NaN
..  ..        ...    ...
150  B 2018-07-29    NaN
151  B 2018-07-30    NaN
152  B 2018-07-31    NaN
153  B 2018-08-01    NaN
154  B 2018-08-02  1.188
```